# xlwings referring to ranges by name even if they are in different sheets

Tags: python, excel, range, xlwings

I cannot understand why this same piece of python code works for my colleagues but not for me

```
`import xlwings as xw
xw.Book('pathofanxlsmfile')
relevantValue1 = xw.Range('nameinsheet1').value
relevantValue2 = xw.Range('nameinsheet2').value
relevantValue3 = xw.Range('nameinsheet3').value`
```

When i run it as a cell in a Jupyter Notebook, it opens the excel file on the last page it was open at. Say it had been sheet1. The value of relevantValue1 is correctly read, but 'nameinsheet2' is not found because it is searched only in sheet1.
Say i have data in many different ranges across many different sheets of an excel book, and i want to read all data from them accessing them by name. Why does the above approach work for my colleagues but not for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, using range you need to select the sheet the defined range exists on, therefore;
if the defined names are defined on the sheet included in the name, i.e. 'nameinsheet1' on Sheet1 'nameinsheet2' on Sheet2 etc then

```
relevantValue1 = xw.Range('nameinsheet1').value
```

will only return if Sheet1 is active and

```
relevantValue2 = xw.Range('nameinsheet2').value
```

if Sheet2 is active and so on. 
Thats how it is operating for me.

However this will return the same data regardless of the active sheet;
Assuming defined names are scoped to the workbook.

```
relevantValue1 = xw.books.active.names('nameinsheet1').refers_to_range.value
relevantValue2 = xw.books.active.names('nameinsheet2').refers_to_range.value
relevantValue3 = xw.books.active.names('nameinsheet3').refers_to_range.value
```